# ASP.NET MVC 3 application redirects to /Account/Logon for all pages, how do I stop it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, deployment, iis-7

I'm trying to deploy an ASP.NET MVC 3 application from my development machine to another workstation. The versions of ASP.NET MVC are the same (3.0.20105), the versions of IIS are the same (7.5.7600.16385), and as far as I can tell the installed versions of the .NET framework are the identical. However, on my dev machine only the routes which hit an `[Authorize]` attribute actually redirect to `~/Account/Logon`, but on the target machine *every* file I try to access redirects me to `~/Account/Logon` (even when I try to access image or stylesheet assets).

I've already seen this question but it doesn't solve the problem for me :

[ASP.NET MVC3 and Windows Auth on IIS keeps redirecting to /Account/Login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009565/asp-net-mvc3-and-windows-auth-on-iis-keeps-redirecting-to-account-login)

I've also tried adding these, but no joy :

```
<add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false" />
<add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false" />
```

Any other ideas?

In case it helps, here's the web.config - it's pretty much unchanged from when I initially created the project :

```
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
    <assemblies>
      <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    </assemblies>
  </compilation>

  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
  </authentication>

  <pages>
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
    </namespaces>
  </pages>
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

And in case this helps, the web.config from the Views folder, though this again is (as far as I can tell) unchanged :

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
  <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      <add namespace="System.Data.Entity" />
    </namespaces>
  </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>

<appSettings>
  <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
</appSettings>

<system.web>
  <httpHandlers>
    <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
  </httpHandlers>

  <pages
      validateRequest="false"
      pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
      pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
      userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
    <controls>
      <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
    </controls>
  </pages>
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />

  <handlers>
    <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
    <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: I've included them, but they're pretty much unchanged from the initial project creation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This came down to configuration in the end. I'm still not entirely sure what the specific permission differences were, but I had to change the identity that the application pool was running under in order to get this working.