# Why Authentication URL is not rendering properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config, forms-authentication, webforms

My Code : 
`<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/CRMLogin/LogOn" timeout="2880"/>
    </authentication>`

I want this :
`http://localhost:13664/CRMLogin/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2fCRM%2fAddNewCRM`

But I am getting this:
`http://localhost:12340/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fCRM%2fAddNewCRM`

I have written in code loginUrl="~/CRMLogin/LogOn" but also why I am getting this Account/Login. I don't know. I tried same in another project but it works fine there. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the following key in your `<appSettings>`:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="loginUrl" value="~/CRMLogin/LogOn" />
    ...
</appSettings>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009565/asp-net-mvc3-and-windows-auth-on-iis-keeps-redirecting-to-account-login) solution, it should prevent the auto redirect to the account controller