# Deploy ASP.net MVC project to IIS and redirect to login.aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, http-status-code-404

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 project that I just deployed to IIS. When I tried to browse the web from the IIS, it always redirect to login.aspx (which I believe I have no such file on my project, I tried to search for login.aspx file on my project and found none). I got this error message:

```
404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

I know there are some questions out there that are similar to mine, but none of the solution provided work on mine. Can you help please? Thank you!

More info:
btw, i'm using windows authentication. here is the code in my web.config file:

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <identity impersonate="true"/>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: How to prevent asp.net from redirecting to login.aspx

Comment: Have you checked out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009565/asp-net-mvc3-and-windows-auth-on-iis-keeps-redirecting-to-account-login ?

Comment: try check the default page in your route.config file where default is set.

Comment: or this could also be due to improper asp.net installation of incorrectly configured iis.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out - 
http://adilmughal.com/blog/2013/02/asp-net-mvc-4-redirects-incorrect-login-url-login-aspx/

Also, if you are using STS or Single sign on, please make sure you remove the WebMatrix.dll and WebMAtrix.data.dll from your project. it will fix this.
check this out at here too - https://meethrishi.wordpress.com/2015/03/29/sts-configuration-mvc-project-takes-you-to-unknow-login-aspx/