# Remove forms authentication on an MVC 4 website

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis, forms-authentication, windows-authentication

### Background

I started an MVC 4, .Net 4.5 website with a view to using Forms authentication, so chose that template. The brief then changed, and I needed to swap to using Windows Authentication instead. This is rolled out onto a Windows Server 2008 box with IIS8.

### The problem

I can't for the life on me turn Forms authentication off. After being authenticated through NTLM successfully, MVC tries to take me to a forms login page. I have tried:

- Changing the web.config to `<authentication mode="Windows" >`
- Changing the IIS application to use "Windows Authentication" as oppose to "Forms Authentication" (Anonymous Authentication is of course, off)
- I have tried commenting out "`AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();`" and "`FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);`" in the `Application_Start()`
- I've tried setting `HttpResponse.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect` in the `Application_EndRequest.`

None of this works. The only horrible fudge that has worked (from a fellow stackoverflow post) was to change the below in the web.config - this has some funky side effects though (bouncing back to Home on navigation when the app shouldn't for instance) :

```
<authentication mode="Windows" >
  <!--<forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />-->
  <forms loginUrl="~/Home" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

### The question

I feel I am missing some blindingly obvious (probably filter related) change I need to make to disable and remove forms auth from the project. Can anyone suggest the steps I need to take to remove in permanently?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is aimed at [webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com)

Comment: The problem is MVC related. The crux of the problem is not IIS or web related, it is MVC related and that has a large Stackoverflow following (74k questions on MVC 4 alone)

Comment: @RowlandShaw nope, seems like a perfectly relevant MVC question related to authentication

Comment: Well, I'd fix it by going into the the IIS management console and disabling Forms authentication for the application;

Comment: That was the second thing I tried @RowlandShaw (as I wrote in "The problem" above) - the settings in IIS are not the problem. Thanks for your interest

Answer (score 6):

[ASP.NET MVC3 and Windows Auth on IIS keeps redirecting to /Account/Login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009565/asp-net-mvc3-and-windows-auth-on-iis-keeps-redirecting-to-account-login)

> Check whether you have WebMatrix.Data.dll and/or WebMatrix.WebData.dll
>   deployed in the bin directory of your application. If they are there
>   (and you know you don't use them) then try removing them and accessing
>   a page that requires authentication.

I removed references in the project to WebMatrix, deleted them from the local bin and the remote bin, and the unexpected behaviour stopped.